# moderncv - align text with image

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I am using the `moderncv` template. when I insert an image, the text gets aligned with the bottom of the image. is there anyway to make it align with the top of the image?

Also, if the text goes into the next line, would it be possible to shift the entire text up instead of down like in the second image?

```
\cventry{\includegraphics[width=\hintscolumnwidth]{pictures/001237.png}}{test}{}{}{}{}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise the image into position:

```
\cventry
  {\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.8\baselineskip}
     {\includegraphics[width=\hintscolumnwidth]{example-image}}}
  {test}{a}{b}{c}{d}
```

[image]

The above output was obtained using [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex).