# how can I insert a logo in the specified image box without interrupting the position of bullet points in moderncv classic?

Tags: moderncv

```
%cventrylogo
\newcommand{\cventrylogo}[9][.25em]{%
\cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
  {}{%                                        V-V arbitrary space
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#8-1em}%
    \vspace{0pt}%
  }%
  {\bfseries#3}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6.}%
  \strut%
  \ifx&#9&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#9\end{minipage}}\fi
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
  {}{%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#8}%
    \vspace{0pt}%
    \includegraphics[width=#8]{#7}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  } } \section{Experience}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%demo%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cventry{02/2020 -- 03/2020\\\includegraphics[width=\hintscolumnwidth]{pictures/image.jpg}}{Position}{\textsc{company name}}{Place}{Country}{}
%\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{•~}
\cvlistitem{description of work}

\cvlistitem{description of work}

\cvlistitem{description of work}
```

[image]

I would like to insert a logo just below the date section on the left-hand. The position of others will remain same. how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a minimal (but complete) code of what you've tried?

Comment: Did you saw question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101766/inserting-an-image-in-cventry-in-moderncv and the answer there? Possible duplicate question?

Comment: @Mensch, I already tried with the code. But there is a big gap

Comment: Did you saw the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306820/16550 ? Possible duplicate? Or answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353261/16550 ?

Comment: Do you have any news for us?